# Assembly reference missing in wcf service application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am creating a Web application using WCF service.

Steps i followed is,

> 1) Created a new WCF Service Application.
>
> 2)Added a new WCF Service.
>
> 3) Created a Class Library.
>
> 4)Added a new class where i am having these codes mentioned below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;


namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public interface IUSerDetails
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails user);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class UserDetails
    {
        string username = string.Empty;
        string password = string.Empty;
        string country = string.Empty;
        string email = string.Empty;
        [DataMember]
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return username; }
            set { username = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set { password = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Country
        {
            get { return country; }
            set { country = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Now in `Ln 13` when i do mousehover on `[OperationContract]`. It Gives an error. **Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference.**

So i thought i missed the namespace

i added 
*using system.ServiceModel;* , but again its showing the same error in both the lines. What is missing out there?

Comment: Is the System.ServiceModel.dll assembly referenced by the project?  If not, that's your issue.  If so, maybe try removing it and re-adding it.

Comment: i think ignore the mousehover error and try to build the solution then check for errors.

Comment: is this resolved? what is the .NET version set for class library?

Answer (score 1):

I was using Visual Studio for Mac to create a new Console project in .NET Framework 4.7.

Oddly it was quite happy with the `[ServiceContract]` attributes coming from `System.ServiceModel` but was complaining about the `[OperationContract]` attributes:

```
Program.cs(10,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OperationContactAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
Program.cs(10,10): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'OperationContact' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)
```

After checking the [OperationContractAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute) documentation I discovered that the `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` assembly was required. For some reason the `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` assembly is not available in the Packages and .NET Assembly tabs via Project References.

I deleted all assemblies from Project References and fixed the above error with NuGet, i.e.:

```bsh
Install-Package System.ServiceModel.Primitives
```

In addition to adding `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` to the Project References it also re-added:

- mscorlib
- System
- System.IdentityModel
- System.Runetime.Serialization
- System.ServiceModel
- System.Xml

Now I can re-add the other assemblies I need to continue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

as per link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96ffb6d7-8737-4c4d-8512-58967d0b69cd/wcf-on-godaddy-compiler-doesnt-recognize-operationcontract?forum=wcf , you need to make two changes. First, add the following line to the httpmodules section of the web.config file:

```
<httpModules>



  <add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>



</httpModules>
```

Second, add the following lines to the assemblies section of the web.config file:

```
  <assemblies>



    <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>



    <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>



  </assemblies>
```

Comment: But i have not edited anything on web.config? How it will miss assembly? Its a new project anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Write [ServiceContract] above the Line "interface IUSerDetails"